# Как удалять изображения в функции delete?

Tags: php, laravel

> Мне нужно чтобы удалялись изображения из папки upload.Например если у
>   пользователя в бд сохранено имя изображения (Esfejih.jpeg) то искалось
>   это изображения в папке и удалялось при срабатывания функции delete()

***в контролере***

```
public function destroy($id){
        $dopysk=Dopysk::find($id);
        $dopysks2='upload/'.$dopysk->spravka035;
        $dopysks1='upload/'.$dopysk->ydostak;
        $dopysks2 ->delete();
        $dopysks1->delete();
        $dopysk->delete();

        return redirect('dopysk');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы поступил малость по другому, немного переписал бы модель Dopysk

```
class Dopys extends Model 
{
    // ваш код
    public function delete()
    {
        unlink(public_storage('upload/'.$this->spravka035));
        unlink(public_storage('upload/'.$this->ydostak));
        return parent::delete();
    }
}
```

И уже после этого переписал бы метод дестрой как он и должен быть

```
 public function destroy(Dopysk $dopysk){
    $dopysk->delete();
    return redirect('dopysk');
}
```

Модель Dopysk ларавел найдёт сам если в роуте в качестве параметра вы передаёте ей ID объекта бд модели. Это поможет вам сохранить нервы и память особенно когда вы будете удалять Dopysk не из метода destroy а из другого связанного метода, вам не придётся каждый раз писать удаление файлов

Answer (score 1):

```
  public function destroy($id){
        $dopysk=Dopysk::find($id);
        $path='upload/'.$dopysk->spravka035;
        $path2='upload/'.$dopysk->ydostak;
        unlink(public_path($path));
        unlink(public_path($path2));
        $dopysk->delete();

        return redirect('dopysk');
    }
```